# Automator workflow to print 4 copies of 1 image on 1 page

Tags: automator, automation

How do I get Automator to print 4 copies of the same image on 1 sheet? I have zilch knowledge about scripts so would appreciate any help!

Comment: by the way, the printer im using is the canon selphy 910

Comment: Here's a good guide on using Automator: http://www.macworld.co.uk/how-to/mac-software/what-automator-can-do-for-you-3605538/. Also, can't you just put the picture in question four times on a single page of a Word/Pages document? That would be the way to go here, I'd say.

Comment: Because I'm having an event and hope to have photos printed automatically as they are added to print queue from the Photobooth without needing someone to be stationed at the mac/printer to change the settings manually :)

Comment: Ah, now I get the meat of your query! I made a hopefully-awesome guide to using Automator with Photo Booth that should help you a lot. Let me know how well it works, and if I can help more; also please upvote it if it helps you!

Comment: Did my answer help you or not?? Please let me know by commenting below my answer (or up here with `@JohnRamos`)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Set up your Automator Recipe

Try doing this to set up Automator:

1. Create a folder named "Photo Booth To Print"
2. Open up the Automator app

   [image: this is automator]

Now inside automator...

3. Go to File->New and choose `Folder Action`.
4. You'll see this bar inside your newly created (still blank) automated workflow: [image: choose folder bar]
   Activate the dropdown menu, and find the `Photo Booth To Print` folder you created in step 1, and select that.
5. On the left side, you'll see a search bar. Search for "Print" and choose "Print Finder Items". Pop that into your workflow (i.e. drag `Print Finder Items` into the center part)
6. Press Command-S to save this Folder Action, and give it a name. Automator will save the Folder Action, attaching it to the selected folder. Now whenever you place anything into this folder, the document will print automatically. (Be careful with your newfound powers, you don't want to accidentally print stuff!)
7. Double-check you did this right by two-finger-clicking on the `Photo Booth To Print` folder in Finder and choosing Services -> Folder Actions Setup. (If you only have a few Services, you may not have a Services menu and will instead see the Folder Actions Setup menu item at the bottom of the contextual menu.) The dialog box that displays will show all the folders to which you have attached Folder Actions. When you click on the folder name, you’ll see the Folder Actions assigned to them.

---

### Now use this with Photo Booth

Now, at your party, pull up Photo Booth and take your photo (I recommend taking using the first mode of three listed (the leftmost in the photo mode selector options) to get four photos taken at once, put into one compiled photo. Once you take this photo, it'll show up in the bar beneath the photo frame; from there, two-finger click on the just-captured photo, choose `export`, and export it into the `Photo Booth To Print` folder, at which point it will print automatically.

---

**Sources and see also**

- Lifehacker's guide to making a DIY photo booth with Automator and the Photo Booth app: http://lifehacker.com/5689177/diy-photo-booth-using-a-mac-and-automator
- Source of Automator Information: http://www.macworld.com/article/1167277/software-utilities/three-great-folder-actions.html
- Learn more about what Automator can do: http://www.macworld.co.uk/how-to/mac-software/what-automator-can-do-for-you-3605538/

Comment: Thank you so much for the comprehensive guide! So sorry as I have been caught up with work. I never thought of that! I was using another Photo Booth app which doesn't collage the photos.

So there isn't a way to actually change the settings of the printer, is it? Because I was actually hoping to print out photos guests post on social media platforms too, on top of the photo booth pictures (ambitious, I know). So the photos get transferred to dropbox via IFTTT and get auto-printed. But if there isn't a way, I'll just stick to printing only the Photo Booth pictures :) 

Thanks again!

Comment: @user190881 Awesome! Since you're new to Stack Exchange, I'll let you know that you can accept my answer as correct by pressing the check mark by the top of my answer.